# Hiding Email Address On UserUpdateForm

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-forms

I want the user to be able to update their username but not email address. In example 3 despite the fact I do not include the field email in my code, the field still appears when I run the site. Admittedly the text box is blank whereas in example 1 and 2 it is populated.

How can I stop the email text box appearing? Or can I lock it so the user cannot enter a new value?

**Example 1**
[image]

```
class UserUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    email = forms.EmailField()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email']
```

**Example 2**
[image]

```
class UserUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    email = forms.EmailField()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['email']
```

**Example 3**

[image]

```
class UserUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    email = forms.EmailField()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username']
```

Comment: Remove the `email` field in the first line of the class, as well as removing it from the `fields` property of the `class Meta`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from django.forms import ModelForm

class UserUpdateForm(ModelForm):
    #email = forms.EmailField()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username']
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you need all other fields except email (or at least you mentioned only email as the one you'd like to hide), perhaps you can use then exclude attribute:

```
from django.forms import ModelForm

class UserUpdateForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = User
         exclude = ('email',)
```

For more details you can read in this [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/modelforms/#selecting-the-fields-to-use).

Also, alternative way to go is to disable field (not checked):

```
class UserUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(disabled=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email']
```

Passing `disabled=True` should still render the field but unable it edition by user.

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.

Comment: @IsmaelPadilla fair point, thanks. I added some more info that may be useful.